# Stepper motor close to PCB/MCU/ADC

Tags: microcontroller, stepper-motor, emc

and I apologize if the question is repeated. I tried to search around, but by my keywords main answers are about control of stepper motor with MCU and this is not my problem.

In my design I want to put the stepper motor just over the MCU and ADC chips. The distance will be about 5-10mm. My main question is whether this will affect the chips in terms of EM noise from the motor or something else. I don't think heat will be a problem.

Thank you!

Edit: The motor is 5V unipolar. I will drive it with DRV8833. I can rotate the motor and thus distance between cables and MCU will be 3 to 5 cm. Main issue remains the motor itself.

Comment: What type of step motor?  Unipolar or bipolar?  Schematic of your driver?

Comment: make a 1cm square loop, solder the loop to a coax cable and find an existing motor to place the loop near --- in 5 or 10 locations and orientations and at 3mm and 5mm and 10mm and 20mm and 50mm distances, and measure and record the voltage. then realize your data means nothing because stepper motors are physically different.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a notification for the edit of the post, so I will write a comment as well. The motor is 5V unipolar. I will drive it with DRV8833. I can rotate the motor and thus distance between cables and MCU will be 3 to 5 cm.

Comment: Hmmmm....it looks like the DRV8833 is for bipolar step motors, yet you say the motor is unipolar.  Is it a hybrid step motor with center-tapped windings?  Or, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will likely experience some EMI issues, not from the motor , but rather the wire routing close to other cables.  If you use twisted pairs, for all cables, this can improve it and then add a ground plane between interfering sources and signals.  Ensure your supply is well filtered for low ripple.  AC connection from 0Vdc to earth ground with 10nF film will also improve immunity.

The EMI is not always what you expect with some PWM switching rate but a spurious resonance in the current limiter with an inductive motor load often heard in the audio range.

Comment: The motor is 5V unipolar. I will drive it with DRV8833. I can rotate the motor and thus distance between cables and MCU will be 3 to 5 cm. I was mainly concerned about the motor itself being in such proximity to the MCU.

Comment: My concern is mutual inductance, M  of V=M*dI/dt which depends on loop area and orientation of current with signal tracks w.r.t. motor current loop.  Can you resolve that?  ADC input impedance makes it easy to accept interference unless you shield signals and keep balanced and then filter.

Comment: It is easy to test with similar inductor current pulse and loop wire to see if 1Meg or 10M probe picks it up in lab tests. Using twisted pair wire loop to probe tip and ring.  Then see how much isolation you can tolerate from acceptable injected filtered spikes with L/R rise time.  Unless you can simulate all parameters , the only way is to conduct lab tests to verify then design accordingly.